# invisible watermark for images

Tags: java, image, watermark

Can someone give me a link to a good tutorial about adding invisible watermarking on images in java.I searched on the net but I couldn't find a tutorial!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216156/how-can-you-hide-information-inside-a-jpg-or-gif-photo

Comment: Another possible duplicate one: [Is there any innovative watermarking technique that doesn't make the watermark obvious?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566030/is-there-any-innovative-watermarking-technique-that-doesnt-make-the-watermark-o)

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to watermark PDF Files , iText provides that feature.

Answer (score 0):

[CLICK HERE](http://www.code.google.com/p/watermarker/) to get the thing you want. You can watermark images without use of any third party although because java provides image and graphics library in j2se version.

Comment: but I also need some code to see how to use that.Cause I have no idea:)

Comment: There are examples in the documentation on that page, and there are also unit tests included in the source for the project.